# How can I make use of mnemonics?

Tags: confusable, mnemonic, pedagogy

During self-study, especially English, I occasionally see suggestions that include **mnemonic rules**. I understand they can help me with studying, but I don't get these ideas.

Here's a typical example:

> Q: [How to mnemonically remember **loose** and **lose**?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19/loose-and-lose-how-to-remember)
>   A: [**Lose** has **lost** one of it's o's.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/25/27)

It sounds a bit messy and difficult to grasp.

Is there a simple explanation how can one make use of mnemonic rules?

Comment: For a close-voter, a relevant discussion on Meta: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29/is-pedagogy-off-topic

Comment: I don't mind questions on pedagogy per se, but this one seems a little too open-ended and general. I wouldn't have a problem with, "Are there any good mnemonics to help me remember X?" if X is related to some nuance of the English language, but I think "How can one use mnemonics?" as a general question is simply too broad. Just my opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mnemonic rules, indeed, help quickly remember some ideas that can't be explained, but only memorized.

English has many words which, due to historic or other reasons, while having **different meaning**, are written similarly to each other. For an English learner, it becomes easy to misspell a word, e.g.:

> *I want to **loose** weight* is incorrect.
>   *I want to **lose** weight* is correct.

## How mnemonic works

Say, you are trying to convey some **meaning**. Let it be "losing weight", or "getting slim".
There are two words with very similar orthography:

- "loose" - to make less tight, or to unfasten
- "lose" - to cause something to stop being in one's possession (**correct**)

The problem is that you don't see a **logical link between meaning and spelling**.
However, if someone tells you:

> **Lose** has **lost** one of its O's

it will clearly tell you: the word stopped having one of its letters, or the word **lost** it. So, now you have:

> I want to say about something lost.
>   The word "lose" has also lost one of its O's
>   Hence, I must use the word "lose".

This way, mnemonics is a tool for artificially linking meaning and spelling.

Usually, it is sufficient to learn a mnemonic rule for a single word of a pair, and by recalling one rule, you will know that the other word will obviously have another spelling.

An extra benefit of mnemonic rules is that they usually have **humorous sense**. Indeed, you can imagine a poor word that walked somewhere and lost one of its letters. The good thing is that jokes are better remembered by human's memory. This makes mnemonics a powerful instrument, especially if you are a beginner and can't (yet) remember formal grammar rules.

Comment: Mnemonics isn't limited to remembering language. Associate each digit 0-9 with an image or event and and you can remember any, even long number as a story of these characters taking part in events.

Comment: @SF. correct, but we must limit the scope and avoid large answers as they may be difficult for *learners*.

Comment: It's a good question and answer, but it would have been nice to define the meaning of mnemonic: a device to aid the *memory*.